# XCode BAD ACCESS when reading argv

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode6, argv

My code was running like a charm until a few minutes ago. I Have already tried to restart XCode, my computer and nothing happens. This is the snippet that matters:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  string input_collection_index;
  string input_directory;
  bool is_retrieval=false;
  bool is_merge = false;


  //Arguments parsing
  for(unsigned i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
    string param  = argv[i];
    //index file name
    if(param == "--index" || param == "-i") {
      i++;
      input_collection_index = argv[i];
    }
    //index file path
    else if (param == "--directory" || param == "-d") {
      i++;
      input_directory = argv[i];
    }
    else if (param == "--retrieval" || param == "-r") {
      is_retrieval = true;
    }
    else if (param == "--merge" || param == "-m"){
      is_merge = true;
    }

  }
}
```

Here is my scheme: 
[image]

I keep receiving the following error: [image]

Note that the address of the bad access is not 0x00, so, it's not null. The XCode debugger shows me that argc has the right length, and that argv (at least argv[0]) is the right string (file path).
Any ideas?

Comment: I just ran that code verbatim, providing similar arguments (-i and -d as presented, similar file and full path args) and have no issues whatsoever. Using Xcode Version 6.3 (6D570). So... this sample *verbatim* (this *exact* code with *nothing* else) faults on your rig?

Comment: Yup. No luck here. I'm on Xcode 6.1  (6A1052d). This is the exact code. Of course there is (way) more stuff after this, but this is exactly what I'm running.

Comment: So closing off the rest of "way more stuff" via block-comment and just letting `main` terminate as you have as above pukes as well?

Comment: Did it. Worked like a charm. No idea why. Any thoughts?

Comment: The answer to that lays in "way more stuff". see if you can spot an accidental mod of either `argc` or `argv` (or better still, if it isn't too hideously long, post it in your question). really hard saying without seeing more code. Sry.

Comment: Yeah, it's huge. bad idea to post it here. I will take a deeper look at the isue. Thanks.

Comment: Also look for potential breaches of array boundaries, etc. Wish you the best of luck, btw.

Comment: Found it.  I was creating a pretty big array inside one class. (unsigned int [9999999]), and it was being allocated statically. Made it dynamic (unsigned int* [] with malloc latter) and everything worked. Thanks again!

Comment: `std::vector<unsigned int>` Seriously. You'll get oodles of benefit and no downside. Inhale deeply and take a big  breath of RAII programming with modern C++. You'll be glad you did =P. Glad you found it.

Comment: It was the original intent. But I'm writing LOTS of data to file later with this. using fwrite() with arrays is pretty faster when writing to file. (unless you know any faster option. If so, I'm all ears!)

Comment: you can still raw-write with `fwrite` against either `vec.data()+index` or `&vec[index]`, depending on your needs. Its doable, just gotta want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is deeper and related do C++, not XCode itself, I think. 
After the snippet above, I was creating a class that had this member:

```
unsigned output_buffer_[9999999];
```

changing it to

```
unsigned *output_buffer_;
```

and then allocating it latter in my code with:

```
output_buffer_ = (unsigned*) malloc(9999999*sizeof(unsigned))
```

made it work.
Maybe something related to how the compiler deals with statically allocated arrays.